# group objects into array with different labels

Tags: javascript, object

```
    {
  '1512': {
    title: 'title1',
  },
  '1513': {
    title: 'title2',
  },
  '1514': {
    title: 'title3',
  },
  '1515': {
    title: 'title4',
  },
  '1516': {
    title: 'title5',
  },
  '1517': {
    title: 'title6',
  },
  '1518': {
    title: 'title7',
  },
}
```

I got the object above, what I am trying to do is create a new array out of it.

For example, I want to check through the object and if title === 'title1' and 'title5' push something like 'title15 combined' <--- not really important but as an example. Then do another check and do if title === 'title2' and 'title3' it would push another item to the new array.

I got the following code but I want it to add one item instead of two items or how many ever conditions match

```js
const data = {
  '1512': {
    title: 'title1',
  },
  '1513': {
    title: 'title2',
  },
  '1514': {
    title: 'title3',
  },
  '1515': {
    title: 'title4',
  },
  '1516': {
    title: 'title5',
  },
  '1517': {
    title: 'title6',
  },
  '1518': {
    title: 'title7',
  },
}

let array = []
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
  if (value.title === 'title1' || value.title === 'title2') {
    array.push('first')
  } else if (value.title === 'title3' || value.title === 'title4') {
    array.push('second')
  }
}

console.log(array)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

So instead of outputting first, first, second, second I want first,second - I feel like the code is also not optimal but ha - let me focus on getting the implementation correct

Comment: *"I want first,second"* - how are we supposed to do that? Your explanation of what you are trying to do is not really helpful.

Comment: Never use "something like" when describing excepted result. Post exact excepted result itself as array in your case and clear explanation.

Comment: @Spectric It's outputting ['first,'first','second','second'] when what I want is to only push one item if condition meets - I'm assuming its pushing two items to the array because two conditions meet but I want it so, if condition meets which in this case value.label === 'title1' and value.label === 'title3' it pushes ONE item to the array

Comment: So, if a condition matches, it should only add one entry, is that correct? Or do you only want sequential matches to be collapsed into only one?

Comment: @VLAZ, exactly - if condition matches just push one entry

Comment: The if conditions match to 4 items in the array, so obviously there are 4 items in the output.

Comment: @Spectric I'm not sure your update to the question is correct. OP said to just push one entry without specifying sequences. You updated the question to say sequential matches should be collapsed. These are two different requirements. With a (potential) output of `[ "first", "second", "second", "first"]` only one non-sequential entry means the expected result is `[ "first", "second"]` while only one sequential entry would be `[ "first", "second", "first"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) that holds a condition you want and the value it needs to be substituted with.

You still need to loop over your object entries but now for each you'd test if any of the map entries matches it. If it does, then add the corresponding value to `array` and remove that condition. That way it will not match again:

```js
const data = {'1512': { title: 'title1', }, '1513': { title: 'title2', }, '1514': { title: 'title3', }, '1515': { title: 'title4', }, '1516': { title: 'title5', }, '1517': { title: 'title6', }, '1518': { title: 'title7', }, };

const substitutions = new Map()
  .set(
    value => value.title === 'title1' || value.title === 'title2',
    'first'
  )
  .set(
    value => value.title === 'title3' || value.title === 'title4',
    'second'
  );

let array = [];
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
  for (const [condition, substituteValue] of substitutions.entries()){
    if (condition(value)) {
      array.push(substituteValue);
      substitutions.delete(condition);
      break;
    }
  }
}

console.log(array)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

This is more maintainable if you want to add more conditions without needing to re-juggle `if/else` chains.

---

If you only want to match titles (rather than more arbitrary conditions), then you can simplify your map definition to include the list of titles as a key. Then you would just need to test `titles.includees(value.title)` in the loop:

```js
const data = {'1512': { title: 'title1', }, '1513': { title: 'title2', }, '1514': { title: 'title3', }, '1515': { title: 'title4', }, '1516': { title: 'title5', }, '1517': { title: 'title6', }, '1518': { title: 'title7', }, };

const substitutions = new Map()
  .set(
    ['title1', 'title2'],
    'first'
  )
  .set(
    ['title3','title4'],
    'second'
  );

let array = [];
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
  for (const [titles, substituteValue] of substitutions.entries()){
    if (titles.includes(value.title)) {
      array.push(substituteValue);
      substitutions.delete(titles);
      break;
    }
  }
}

console.log(array)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Perfect - what I was looking for, in terms of pushing stuff to the array, you see how we got 'first', How would I be able to do it so I push array of object? so {label: 'first', id: 0} then {label: 'second', id: 1}

Comment: Just change the value in the map. For example replace `'first'` with `{label: 'first', id: 0}` and you'd push that object to the output instead.

Comment: You see in second snippet - I was thinking, Lets say my objects was like this:  {'1512': { title: 'title1', code: 1982 }, '1512': { title: 'title3', code: 2009 } etc. In terms of pushing items to the array, would it also be possible in this instance to push {label: 'first', codes: [1982, 2009]} so the output also has a new codes array which has the code etc

Answer (score 0):

Store the previous value in a variable, then perform checks using an `if` statement:

```js
const data = {
  '1512': {
    title: 'title1',
  },
  '1513': {
    title: 'title2',
  },
  '1514': {
    title: 'title3',
  },
  '1515': {
    title: 'title4',
  },
  '1516': {
    title: 'title5',
  },
  '1517': {
    title: 'title6',
  },
  '1518': {
    title: 'title7',
  },
}

let array = [];
let last;
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
  if (value.title === 'title1' || value.title === 'title2') {
    if (last != 'first') {
      array.push('first')
      last = 'first';
    }
  } else if (value.title === 'title3' || value.title === 'title4') {
    if (last != 'second') {
      array.push('second')
      last = 'second';
    }
  }
}

console.log(array)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Or read the last element in the array:

```js
const data = {
  '1512': {
    title: 'title1',
  },
  '1513': {
    title: 'title2',
  },
  '1514': {
    title: 'title3',
  },
  '1515': {
    title: 'title4',
  },
  '1516': {
    title: 'title5',
  },
  '1517': {
    title: 'title6',
  },
  '1518': {
    title: 'title7',
  },
}

let array = [];
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
  let prev = array[array.length-1];
  if (value.title === 'title1' || value.title === 'title2') {
    if (prev != 'first') {
      array.push('first')
    }
  } else if (value.title === 'title3' || value.title === 'title4') {
    if (prev != 'second') {
      array.push('second')
    }
  }
}

console.log(array)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know if there were any matches, just have an object with the keys for each test and set their default to false. Then just turn them to true if they have a match.

```js
const data = {
  '1512': {
    title: 'title1',
  },
  '1513': {
    title: 'title2',
  },
  '1514': {
    title: 'title3',
  },
  '1515': {
    title: 'title4',
  },
  '1516': {
    title: 'title5',
  },
  '1517': {
    title: 'title6',
  },
  '1518': {
    title: 'title7',
  },
}

const cases = {
  first: false,
  second: false,
}


let array = []
for (const [_, v] of Object.entries(data)) {
  if (v.title === 'title1' || v.title === 'title2') cases.first = true;
  if (v.title === 'title3' || v.title === 'title4') cases.second = true;
}

console.log(cases);
```